# Solving higher order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve this initial value problem:

$$5y^{(3)}+ 2y'' = 0 , y(0) = 4 , y'(0) = 2, y''(0) = 8$$

The only method we have learned is to assign variables to each degree, and then make a matrix to solve the equation. So, for this problem, would I do something like this?

$$a = y, b = y', c = y'' \\
a' = b\\
b' = c\\
c' = -2c/5$$

And then plug into the matrix? 
Note: the $y^{(3)}$ is a third derivative; I tried formatting and it didn't work

Comment: **Hint:** What if we write $5 m^3 + 2 m^2 = 0 \implies m_{1,2,3} = 0, 0, -\dfrac{2}{5}$? We can now write $y_c(x) = c_1 + c_2 x + c_3 e^{-2/5 x}$.Now, use your ICs to find the constants.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the equation has constant coefficients the solutions have the form $y = e^{rx}$. If you plug this into the differential equation you get $5r^3 + 2r^2=0$, which has a root of $-2/5$ and a repeated root of $0$. The general solution is a linear combination of $e^{0x}=1$, $xe^{0x}=x$, and $e^{-2x/5}$.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it like this
$$5y^{(3)}+2y''=0$$
Let $y''=g(x)$
then
$$5g'+2g=0$$
So,
$$g(x)=ce^{-2x/5}$$
and
$g(0)=8$,
Hence 
$$y''(x)=8e^{-2x/5}$$
$$y'(x)=c-20e^{-2x/5}$$
$$y'(0)=2$$
Hence
$$y'(x)=22-20e^{-2x/5}$$
$$y(x)=c+22x+50e^{-2x/5}$$
$$y(0)=4$$
So
$$y(x)=50e^{-2x/5}+22x-46$$